# mktime() gives different results than Howard Hinnant's date library (std::chrono based)

Tags: c++, date, c++-chrono, mktime

I am using Howard Hinnant's date C++ library (https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html), but I have some confusions using it. Below is a program where I use this library to print the year-month-day of the 3rd Friday of Nov 2017. The `date::year_month_weekday` class, when used with `date::sys_days()`, shows a correct date (Nov 17, 2017), but when I convert it to `struct tm` with `std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t`, the results stored in this `tm` becomes Nov 16, 2017. I tested other cases, it seems `struct tm` converted from `date::year_month_weekday` always one day behind. Did I miss something in my program? The program is listed as below, C++ 11 is needed to compile it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include "date.h"

using namespace std; 
using namespace std::chrono; 
using namespace date;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {  
    date::year y(2017);
    date::month m(11);
    date::weekday wd((unsigned)5);
    date::weekday_indexed wi(wd,3);
    date::year_month_weekday dmwd(y, m, wi);
    std::cout <<  date::sys_days(dmwd) << std::endl; //prints 2017-11-17, which is the 3rd Friday of Nov 2017

    time_t tt = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(date::sys_days(dmwd));        
    struct tm tm1;
    localtime_r(&tt, &tm1);
    std::cout << "tm1.tm_year = " << tm1.tm_year << std::endl;
    std::cout << "tm1.tm_mon = " << tm1.tm_mon << std::endl;
    std::cout << "tm1.tm_mday = " << tm1.tm_mday << std::endl;  //prints 16 instead of 17, one day behind. tm.mday is from 1 to 31.

    return 0; 
}
```

The output of this program is as follows

```
2017-11-17
tm1.tm_year = 117  <-- 117+1900=2017
tm1.tm_mon = 10    <-- tm_mon starts form 0, so 10 means November
tm1.tm_mday = 16  <-- tm_mday starts from 1, so 16 is the 16-th day in a month
```

Comment: Have you tried using `gmtime_r()` instead of `localtime_r()`?

Comment: Yes, I just tried, `gmtime_r` did give the consistent result, thank for the hint. Since the `date::year_month_weekday` contains no time (hour and minute) info, I wonder how the date library deals with it when converting to `struct tm`. I also print the `tm_hour` and `tm_min` of the `struct tm` converted from `date::year_month_weekday`. It seems `tm_hour == 18` and `tm_min == 0` for all the cases -- probably because I am in a UTC-6 time zone?

Comment: Fwiw, here is alternative syntax to create `dmwd`:  `auto dmwd = fri[3]/nov/2017;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Howard Hinnant's date.h](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) tracks [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) which for most practical purposes is UTC.  At this same [GitHub repository](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) there is also a [timezone library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) if you need to deal with your local time, or with any timezone other than UTC.

So yes, as Freddie Chopin noted in the comments, you are seeing the effects of `localtime_r` taking your computer's local timezone into account.

You can add any time of day to `sys_days` that you want.  `sys_days` is a `std::chrono::time_point`, but with `days` precision.  So once you have `sys_days`, you are actually within the `<chrono>` library now, instead of the date library:

```
system_clock::time_point t = date::sys_days(dmwd) + 6h + 53min + 4s + 123us:
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation. Just another question, I tried to change `sys_days(dmwd)` to `local_days(dmwd)`, but it won't compile, saying something about no matching function. What is the correct way to use `local_days`? Should I add the timezone library to my program as well? Thanks again!

Comment: @WorkOnly:  I just tried that experiment and it compiled for me.  Which compiler/version?  Can you set up a demo at some place such as: https://wandbox.org ?  Here's a sandbox to start with: https://wandbox.org/permlink/HMMMIqtuG6Ia1AHY .

Comment: I can compile the program in my original post without problem, but when I replaced `sys_days(dmwd)` with `local_days(dmwd)`, it gives the following error message (gcc 5.4 on Ubuntu 16.04, with `g++ -std=c++11 date_time.cpp`):
`date_time.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
date_time.cpp:18:73: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::to_time_t(date::local_days)’
  time_t tt = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(date::local_days(dmwd));
                                                                         ^
In file included from date_time.cpp:2:0:`

Comment: (continued) `/usr/include/c++/5/chrono:734:7: note: candidate: static time_t std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::to_time_t(const time_point&)
       to_time_t(const time_point& __t) noexcept
       ^
/usr/include/c++/5/chrono:734:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘date::local_days {aka std::chrono::time_point<date::local_t, std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<86400l, 1l> > >}’ to ‘const time_point& {aka const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >&}’`

Comment: @WorkOnly:  Ok, that makes sense.  `system_clock::to_time_t` takes a `system_clock::time_point` as an argument.  `sys_days` is a typedef for a coarse `system_clock::time_point` and implicitly converts to `system_clock::time_point`.  Whereas `local_days` is a `chrono::time_point` with no relationship whatsoever to `system_clock`.  The compile-time error serves to keep you from accidentally mixing up these two families of `time_point`s.

Comment: In my own experiment I replaced the wrong `date::sys_days(dmwd)`. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, Howard. (Sorry I don't know how to @ here)